# Matlab symbolic solve circle of known radius between two points

Tags: matlab

I would like to find the center of the circle that passes between two points A and B, knowing the (x,y) pairs of both points, as well as the circle radius.

This should produce two pairs of center candidates, [Xcenter1, Ycenter1] and [Xcenter2, Ycenter2], respectively. They correspond to the center of the circle to the left and to the right of segment [AB].

I have written the following symbolic Matlab script:

```
syms x1 y1 x2 y2 xc yc r
f1 =  (x1-xc)^2 + (y1-yc)^2 - r^2;
f2 =  (x2-xc)^2 + (y2-yc)^2 - r^2;

solve(f1,f2,'xc,yc')
```

The result of which is:

```
ans = 
xc: [2x1 sym]
yc: [2x1 sym]
```

From this [thread](http://www.mathworks.es/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255121), the result should look like:

```
xc1 = x1/2 + x2/2 - (y1*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2 + (y2*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2

xc2 = -(2*y1*(y1/2 + y2/2 - (x1*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2 + (x2*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2) - 2*y2*(y1/2 + y2/2 - (x1*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2 + (x2*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2) - x1^2 + x2^2 - y1^2 + y2^2)/(2*x1 - 2*x2)

yc1 = y1/2 + y2/2 + (x1*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2 - (x2*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2

yc2 = y1/2 + y2/2 - (x1*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2 + (x2*(-(x1^2 - 4*r^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - 2*x1*x2 + x2^2 + y1^2 - 2*y1*y2 + y2^2))^(1/2))/2
```

What could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: link was incorrect, I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the function without storing it's output, Matlab stores the output automatically in a variable called `ans`. That variable is not reliable, because a subsequent call to another function with non-assigned outputs may override the value of `ans`.

In the specific case of `solve`, it has some ways of accessing it's output (see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html)). By default it returns a struct containing the function variables (in this case, `xc` and `yc`). As no variable was assigned, the `ans` variable stored this struct.

Try calling `solve` this way:

```
[xc,yc] = solve(f1,f2,'xc,yc')
```

Now you have it's outputs (`xc` and `yc`) and can use them as you intended. You could also call the function this way:

```
S = solve(f1,f2,'xc,yc')
```

Then you'll have `S.xc` and `S.yc`, stored as a struct.

Comment: Even though the problem and solution are basic, this answer is not particularly useful or valuable to other who might come across this in the future. You should at least explain what was happening in the first case when `solve` was returning a struct and also how one might also use the out put of the struct.